# Select all characters in a string until a specific character Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, visual-studio

So what I want is to get n characters until it hits a specific character.

i have this String :

```
a='2.452811139617034,42.10874821716908|3.132087902867818,42.028314077306646|-0.07934861041448178,41.647538468746916|-0.07948265046522918,41.64754863599606'
```

How can I make it to only get to the character | , but without getting that character,
and get it like this:

```
2.452811139617034,42.10874821716908
```

Comment: What do you want returned if the string does not contain a pipe character (`'|'`)?

Comment: @CarySwoveland great question. I would need to add a logical operation to my answer in this case where as you would not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid creating an unnecessary Array (like `Array#split`) or using a Regex (like `Array#gsub`) by using.

```
a = "2.452811139617034,42.10874821716908|3.132087902867818,42.028314077306646|-0.07934861041448178,41.647538468746916|-0.07948265046522918,41.64754863599606"

a[0,a.index('|')]
#=>"2.452811139617034,42.1087482171"
```

This means select characters at positions 0 up to the index of the first pipe (`|`). Technically speaking it is start at position 0 and select the length of n where n is the index of the pipe character which works in this case because ruby uses 0 based indexing.

As @CarySwoveland astutely pointed out the string may not contain a pipe in which case my solution would need to change to

```
#to return entire string
a[0,a.index('|') || a.size]
# or
b = a.index(?|) ? a[0,b] : a
# or to return empty string
a[0,a.index('|').to_i]
# or to return nil
a[0,a.index(?|) || -1]
```

Comment: Interesting.  I didn’t realize we could use ```string[]```that way.  Alternatively though, we could also use ```a[0…a.index("|")]``` which seems to be a bit more familiar.

Comment: @MichaelB but it creates a Range which is also an unnecessary object creation and I would argue that exclusive (triple dot) ranges not all that familiar

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do it like this:

`a.split('|').first`

Comment: I would suggest using ```partition``` instead of ```split``` . Partition will stop looking after the first match while split will keep going throughout the entire string.

Comment: @MichaelB - That's easy to "fix" with `split('|', 2)`, however I don't think the performance gain would be noticeable (unless the string is really long...)

Comment: worked for me on 2023

Answer (score 2):

I'm always curious as to the performance of various options and so I took the liberty of looping through some of the approaches suggested.  I named them as follows:

```
split_all = a.split('|').first
partition = a.partition('|').first
split_two = a.split('|', 2).first
string_brack_args = a[0,a.index('|')]
string_brack_range = a[0...a.index('|')]
gsub_regex = a.gsub(/\|.*$/, "")
plain_regex = a[/[^|]+/]
```

---

The results were as follows (slowest at top):

```
   user     system      total        real
gsub_regex           0.170000   0.000000   0.170000 (  0.162666)
split_all            0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.109498)
split_two            0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.041792)
partition            0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.037161)
string_brack_range   0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.034021)
plain_regex          0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.033468)
string_brack_args    0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.022455)
```

That's nearly an eight-fold increase in efficiency between the slowest and fastest.  Even some of the little things make a huge difference.  Granted, I looped through these 100_000 times, so the difference is pretty small for the one instance, but even something as simple as using using `split(str, 2)` vs `split(str)` is well over twice as fast.  In fact, the faster half of the approaches listed average 3 times as fast as the slower half.

Answer (score 1):

One approach uses a `gsub` replacement:

```rb
a = "2.452811139617034,42.10874821716908|3.132087902867818,42.028314077306646|-0.07934861041448178,41.647538468746916|-0.07948265046522918,41.64754863599606"
output = a.gsub(/\|.*$/, "")
puts output  # 2.452811139617034,42.10874821716908
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a[/[^|]+/]
  #=> "2.452811139617034,42.10874821716908"
```

The regular expression simply matches as many characters other than `'|'` that it can.